# How to round a decimal number to the nearest thousandths in c

Tags: c, rounding

I want a c program to round a decimal number to the thousandths position (the third position to the right of the decimal point)

Comment: The thousandths position is the *third* to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Then you should attempt to write one. (The 2nd position is the 'hundredths' column)

Comment: @MikeCAT: You closed a problem asking about rounding to positions to the right of the decimal point as a duplicate about rounding to positions to the left of the decimal point. These are fundamentally different questions, in part due to the fact that binary floating-point cannot represent most decimal numerals with three digits to the right of the decimal point but can represent in-range decimal numerals with significant digits ending to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: add 0.0005 then truncate ? I don't know if floating type precision woud allow such a thing to be really accurate though.

Comment: `#include <math.h>` and `round(x*1000)/1000`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson `round(x*1000.0)/1000` is better should `x` be a `float`.  Scaling by a `double` rather than an `int` affords more precision and range.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that C does not support *decimal* numbers natively, only binary.  So any time you deal with decimal numbers, you generally need to convert them to binary (on input) and then convert them back to decimal on ouput.  C supports two kinds of binary numbers (binary integers and binary floating-point), so this leads to two ways of dealing with it

- use binary integers (`int` or `long`).  For decimal integers this is fine, but if you have decimal fractions, this works less well.  You end up needing to pick a (generally fixed) denominator and work with all numbers as being implicitly multiplied by that.  In your case you might have a fixed denominator of `1000` to get (always) 3 decimal places, but converting input and output is hard
- use binary floating point.  The problem is that binary floating point cannot exactly represent decimal fractions, so you end up rounding things.  As long as you are aware of this rounding (so you value may be off by some small epsilon value) this is ok, but you may be suprised, particularly if you convert the floating point values to binary integers, which truncates rather than rounding.  Careful use of the `round` function can avoid problems here.

So how to handle your case?  It depends on what you want to do.  If you just want to read a decimal value then write it back out rounded to 3 places, that is easiest with floating point:

```
double val;
scanf("%f", &val);   /* read a decimal value */
printf("%.3f", val); /* write it with 3 digits after the decimal (rounding to nearest) */
```